# My webView activity shows blank

Tags: java, android, webview

Am Trying to add webview on my android activity but its the activity page does not shows my given url please help me.?

DMS.java

```
  package com.agte.vivo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class Dms extends Activity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dms);
        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    //myWebView.loadData("yourCode Html to load on the webView " , "text/html" , "utf-8");

    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }});
    myWebView.loadUrl("192.168.7.175/app/app.html");

    }


    }
```

Activity DMS

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.agte.vivo.Dms">


    <WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

there is no error shown but i need to to open the webpage same in android app how to fix this.?

Comment: Is the web page: 192.168.7.175/app/app.html accessible?

Comment: no am currently add my website as local host its my ip of system

Comment: ok can i get google site using this in same window.?

Comment: yes I would suggest changing 192.168.7.175/app/app.html to http://www.google.com to chek that the issue is not in the code but in the availability of the website.

Comment: yes i fix that how can i access my own local host website in this

Comment: Working with Android's WebView is just a headache.  You can check this : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VBCVnxe2ZEg

Answer (score 1):

Did you add this line in your manifest file ?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  try this:
        //if you have your html file in assets folder do like this
        // aboutWebview .loadUrl("file:///android_asset/About.html");
        WebView aboutWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.aboutus_webview);
        aboutWebview .loadUrl("http://192.168.7.175/app/app.html");
        WebSettings webSettings = aboutDmrWebview.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        aboutWebview .addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this), "Android");
        aboutDmrWebview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());


      private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("www.google.com")) {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load the page
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "www.google.com", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: sir how can i access local host site in app

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see there is nothing wrong with the code. Your issue is because you are trying to access a URL which is not available, since it is not yet exposed to the internet.

Just for the sake of testing that there is nothing wrong in the url, I recommend changing `192.168.7.175/app/app.html` to a more plausable website such as `http://www.google.com` for the time being.

Your next step is to find a way to expose your website to the web, so that it is accessible from your device. If you have IIS installed, you can copy your website content to the `C:\inetpub\www` folder. This would expose (make it available on the web) your site to anyone knowing the url. You can also use [this tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/accessing-localhost-from-anywhere/) to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you use the same Wifi network as your computer