# Am using webView method to view my form in android app but it is not fit to screen in mobile how fix that.?

Tags: android, html, css, webview

I think its my `html` / `css` problem . I already got my web view correctly its from 
[My webView activity shows blank](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39075171/6399707)

Below are my html and css part

**index.html**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Collection</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="insert.css">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<div class="maindiv">
<!--HTML Form -->
<div class="form_div">
<div class="title">
<h2>Insert Data In Database .</h2>
</div>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<!-- Method can be set as POST for hiding values in URL-->
<h2>Form</h2>
<label>Name:</label>
<input class="input" name="name" type="text" value="">
<label>Number:</label>
<input class="input" name="number" type="text" value="">
<label>Shop:</label>
<input class="input" name="shop" type="text" value="">
<label>item:</label>
<input class="input" name="item" type="text" value="">
<label>Collection:</label>
<textarea cols="25" name="collection" type="textarea" value="" rows="5"></textarea><br>
<input class="submit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Insert">
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**insert.css**

```
   .maindiv {
margin:30px auto;
width:980px;
height:500px;
background:#fff;
padding-top:20px;
font-family:'Droid Serif',serif;
font-size:14px
}
.title {
width:500px;
height:70px;
text-shadow:2px 2px 2px #cfcfcf;
font-size:16px;
text-align:center
}
.form_div {
width:70%;
float:left
}
form {
width:300px;
border:1px dashed #aaa;
padding:10px 30px 40px;
margin-left:70px;
background-color:#f0f8ff
}
form h2 {
text-align:center;
text-shadow:2px 2px 2px #cfcfcf
}
textarea {
width:100%;
height:60px;
border-radius:1px;
box-shadow:0 0 1px 2px #123456;
margin-top:10px;
padding:7px;
border:none
}
.input {
width:100%;
height:30px;
border-radius:2px;
box-shadow:0 0 1px 2px #123456;
margin-top:10px;
padding:7px;
border:none;
margin-bottom:20px
}
.submit {
color:#fff;
border-radius:3px;
background:#1F8DD6;
padding:5px;
margin-top:40px;
border:none;
width:100%;
height:30px;
box-shadow:0 0 1px 2px #123456;
font-size:18px
}
p {
color:red;
text-align:center
}
span {
text-align:center;
color:green
}
```

Am attaching screenshot I got like this in app i would like to change permanent without scroll in my app what can i do any one help .?

[image: screen]

Comment: What is your question? Didn't get you!

Comment: ya i need to fit the screen in the above form without scroll option

Comment: improved explanations

Comment: ya sorry i mean just the web page shows in above screen shot in my app

Answer (score 0):

You have to add meta Viewport and check for screen density. You can find more detail [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/targeting.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8735457/scale-fit-mobile-web-content-using-viewport-meta-tag).

Comment: where will i add this

Comment: in the html page, index.html page

Comment: Please edit your answer: A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: ya but i have got the same problem till now in my application